# Keeping shell configurations in sync across multiple machines

Tags: shell, synchronization, development-environment, dotfiles

I'm a pretty active command line user and I have shell accounts all over the place. MacBooks, Linux desktop machines, Linux servers, Cygwin on XP, you name it.

How can I keep my shell configuration (`.bashrc`, `.vimrc` etc.) in sync across all these machines using the limited tools available across all platforms?

I have been using `rsync` in a pretty limited manner that involves manually copying some files over when I need them, but I want a standard way for setting up the same basic shell environment across all my machines. Tell me your shell account management strategy.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have folder on Dropbox with global, per OS, and per machine shell configs:

```
$ ls ~/Dropbox/shell/bash
bashbootstrap  bashrc
bashrc-Darwin  bashrc-Darwin-laptopname  bashrc-Darwin-mininame
bashrc-Linux  bashrc-Linux-machineone  bashrc-Linux-machinetwo
```

`bashrc` is loaded on every machine, `bashrc-Linux`, `bashrc-Darwin` are loaded on their respective OSes, and several configs are specific to individual machines. (By the way, Darwin is the name of OS X's BSD-like kernel.)

What ties it all together is the `bashbootstrap` file. It loads each applicable config file in order of increasing specificity, this allows per OS and per machine overrides to have higher precedence. Additionally, we silently skip missing config files; you need not create empty config files for each of your machines to keep the script happy.

On a new machine, after installing Dropbox on `~/Dropbox`, I move away the default `.bashrc` and just symlink the bootstrap file in its place instead:

```
$ mv ~/.bashrc ~/.bashrc.bak
$ ln -s ~/Dropbox/shell/bash/bashbootstrap  ~/.bashrc
```

Oh, and here are the contents of the `bashbootstrap` file:

```
if [ -z "$PS1" ]; then
   return
fi

dropboxshelldir=~/Dropbox/shell
dropboxdir=$dropboxshelldir/bash
masterbashrc=$dropboxdir/bashrc
osbashrc=$masterbashrc-`uname`
localbashrc=$osbashrc-`hostname | cut -d. -f1`

echo -n "Applicable shell configs: "
for bashfile in "$masterbashrc" "$osbashrc" "$localbashrc"; do
  if [ -r $bashfile ]; then
    . $bashfile
    echo -n "`basename $bashfile` "
  fi
done
echo

# Set convenience aliases
myed=${VISUAL:-${EDITOR:-vim}}
alias editbashrc="$myed $masterbashrc"
alias editosbashrc="$myed $osbashrc"
alias editlocalbashrc="$myed $localbashrc"
```

One final note, this script also provides three convenience aliases for editing your Bash config files without having to remember where they are stored.

- **`editbashrc`:** Edit the global config file.
- **`editosbashrc`:** Edit the OS-specific config file.
- **`editlocalbashrc`:** Edit the machine-specific config file.

I only tested this on Bash, but it could work on other Bash like shells. But, as they say, your mileage may vary.

I made a blog post about this [here](http://paksoy.net/post/159917345/how-dropbox-saved-my-command-line).

Answer (score 2):

I've used version control for this in the past ([svn](http://subversion.tigris.org/), [mercurial](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/wiki/), etc...).  You can set up your own server, or use a hosted one.  [Dropbox](http://www.getdropbox.com) also works.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to source control, I'd just check them in.  This way you get to sync them across multiple machines and you can compare/roll-back if need be.  If you don't have  CVS/SVN at work there are free options available.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer slightly different configuration files for Vim, Fish, Sway, etc. on different machines, so I made a program (filetailor) to handle this and then sync the result with Git.

[filetailor](https://github.com/k4j8/filetailor) is an open-source Python program that can make small changes to files using device-specific variables or using device-specific comments in the files.

For example, the following line would be commented out on every device except the one with hostname `device1`.

```
alias MYHOME='/home/dev1home/' #{filetailor device1}
```